# is it so that some manufacturer's device does not support "support library"

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I want to create an application for android, in which i want to use `AsyncTaskLoader` and `FragmentActivity`. I've kept minimum sdk version to 8 `android:minSdkVersion="8"`. Therefore i have to import `import android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader;` , `import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;` & 
`import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;` in my code. But the problem is that when i tested the application on Standard Manufacturers device such as SAMSUMG, LG etc.. the application runs perfectly but on some manufacturers(which i would not like to mention) devices the application force closes as soon as it starts and when when i saw the `stacktrace` i found that it was because of the `supportlibrary` error.

Can anyone tell me how can i make my application compatible with all kind of devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely in the Device's /system/framework/framework.jar file.

Sometimes, you can actually compile the .jar files you need by taking the source from a device that works and compiling parts of the Framework.jar separately to make the .jar library you need.

Then include it as a source in your project. However, I would double check to see that you do not mess up other running services because essentially, you would be accessing your own hidden api which is normally already a hidden API in the Google API. (hint AsyncTaskLoader).

assume you already have the android-support-v4.jar in your libs.

Comment: can you explain me the process step by step. i am newbie in android application development

Comment: To use Hidden API's or just for how to add in good framework jars, take a look at this: https://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-1-introduction/